# Getting a video views with Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, video

I want to get the video count of the videos on my pages but all the informations I can get are informations about crossposted videos but my videos are not crossposted.

I played with the Graph API explorer quite a bit without arriving to a solution.

```
/{pages_id_video_id}/insights/post_video_views
```

And everything I tried only gave me an empty "data" array.

Comment: Still using this video_insights? I can't use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First please be sure you have a token with `read_insights` permission !**
You can check your token here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/

You can explore the Facebook API here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

You can get all your videos insight for a page with this request:

```
/PAGE_ID/videos?fields=video_insights
```

If you want only insights for one video use this request:

```
/VIDEO_ID/video_insights/total_video_views/lifetime
```

You can change period (accepted values are *{day, week, days_28, month, lifetime, total_over_range}*) and what you information you want *(total_video_views_unique, total_video_views_autoplayed, total_video_views_clicked_to_play ...)* the first request listing all videos from a page will give you all the possibility ;)

Comment: can we get the user videos views which are uploaded by user on his own profile...?

Comment: someone trying using this in 2019? Not working for me (v4.0) @Mathieu